# Describe the distributional derivative of $f$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be a piece wise defined function with piece wise continuous derivative. Describe the distributional derivative of $f$.

My try:

If I suppose that the jump discontinuities are at the points $-1$,$0$ and $1$. Then I will look to generalize it. Then I have $$\left(\frac{d}{dx}f,\phi\right)=-\left(f,\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right)=-\left(\int_{-a}^{-1}f\frac{d\phi}{dx}+\int_{-1}^{0}f\frac{d\phi}{dx}+\int_{0}^{1}f\frac{d\phi}{dx}+\int_{1}^{a}f\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right)$$ where $Supp \phi=[-a,a]$.

It will eventually come out to be $(f',\phi)$. 
Intuitively I think there has to be delta function somewhere.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Integrating by parts, $$\int_c^d  f \dfrac{d\phi}{dx} = f(d-) \phi(d) - f(c+) \phi(c) - \int_c^d \dfrac{df}{dx} \phi$$

Comment: That is exactly what I did.

Comment: What I am asking is if what I did is correct or not?

Comment: Correct so far, but there's more to do.  Do you see how the $\delta$ functions come out of the difference between the one-sided limits of $f$ at the discontinuities?

Comment: more like what?? I can generalize it to finite no of discontinuities.

Comment: I don't see how??

Comment: If there's a jump at $x=c$, $f(c+) \phi(c) - f(c-) \phi(c) = (f(c+)-f(c-)) \phi(c) = (f(c+)-f(c-)) \int \phi(x) \delta(x-c)\; dx$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!